# MobX - Update multiple store array items at once?

Tags: mobx

I have 4 stores for a stack overflow example:

```
SearchQuestionsStore
RecentQuestionsStore
UserQuestionsStore
CurrentQuestionStore
```

Each of the first 3 stores have an `@observable questionsList = [];`

A question may be accessed from any of those 3 stores, when the `questionsList` is populated with questions. An `@observable currentQuestion` holds the current selected question in the `CurrentQuestionStore`

If a user upvotes the `currentQuestion`, we simply increment the current question's count using `CurrentQuestionStore.currentQuestion.upvotes++`, but this does not reflect the latest upvote count in the other 3 stores.

The issue is that the question may or may not exist in any of the other 3 stores `questionlists`, so I was wondering what would be the best way to approach this using MobX? So we can update the latest count for this `questionId = 1` across all stores if they exist. The same situation occurs when changing the title, answers count, or any other attribute on the `currentQuestion`

What's the best way to reflect the changes of any attribute change across the stores at once?

Comment: Have you tried just using just one `QuestionStore` for all questions, and having just one object as `currentQuestion`? It seems like you maybe use to many stores for your use case.

Comment: Nope, but it looks like that's the way to go for single source of truth!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MobX, you should never have two copies of the same thing. The same question object should be referenced from all stores. To achieve this, it will depend on how your code is setup to load and store the questions.

One way I suggest doing this is to have an `AllQuestionsStore` that contains all questions in a map:

```
class AllQuestionsStore {
  @observable questionsMap = asMap({});

  @action addQuestion(question) {
    const map = this.questionsMap;
    if (map.has(question.id)) {
      extendObservable(map.get(question.id), question);
    } else {
      map.set(question.id, question);
    }
    return map.get(question.id);
  }
}
```

Then you whenever you create or load a question, you should add it to this store. For example, when you load user questions from the server:

```
function loadedUserQuestions(userQuestions) {
  const questions = userQuestions.map(AllQuestionsStore.addQuestion, AllQuestionsStore);
  UserQuestionsStore.questionsList = questions;
}
```

And if you want to set the current question:

```
CurrentQuestionStore.currentQuestion = AllQuestionsStore.addQuestion(question);
```

Now it's guaranteed that a question has only one instance, so if you update it, other stores will never be out of date.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggested approach, I am trying it out but running into an issue. After the `loadedUserQuestions` runs, the questions populate the `AllQuestionsStore.questionsMap` which is great. The issue occurs the second time  `loadedUserQuestions` runs, specifically this line errors out `map.get(question.id).merge(question);` with this error `map.get(...).merge is not a function` It seems to occur only when the `map.has(question.id)` runs. Logging it out shows the `question.id` and `question` both exist there, so not sure what's causing the error. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Whoops! Yeah of course, that was my bad. I'll edit the answer to correct it.

Comment: It now errors out when extending an `observable` with an `observable`, adding toJS seems to work `extendObservable(map.get(question.id), toJS(question));` Found issue #540 on github, which the error lead me to :)

Comment: I added a question related to deleting via map based on your approach [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41007686/mobx-remove-multiple-store-observable-array-objects-via-map-delete-at-once) Please let me know if you know how to solve it :)